# Could the low Higgs mass be relevant to the unification of the (weak) nuclear force and gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity, higgs, weak-interaction, electroweak, unified-theories

I found in a paragraph in a research paper (although it was talking about something else) the statement: that it is possible to unite the weak nuclear force and gravity, but that requires that:

1. Both the Fermi scale for weak interactions and the Planck scale (gravity) have the same value.
2. Both the Fermi constant and the gravitational constant have the same value.
3. The weak nuclear force is the same force as gravity

But when I researched this matter, I found:

1. The weak nuclear force is much stronger than the gravitational force.
2. The Fermi scale is much smaller than the Planck scale.
3. That if the standard model is used in calculating the quantum corrections to the Fermi constant, the Fermi constant will have a value close to the gravitational constant and could be much closer unless there is a cancellation between the abstract value (which was observed experimentally in particle colliders) and the quantum corrections for him
   Or alternatively (which caught my attention in the paper) the Higgs boson must have a much smaller mass than Planck's mass.
   The observational results of the Higgs boson mass seem to support this
4. It seems that the Higgs mechanism, along with the gauge invariance that protects the weak nuclear force bosons from acquiring masses equal to the Planck mass, can explain (to some extent) the significant difference between the Fermi scale and the Planck scale.

So does the very low Higgs mass indicate that the weak nuclear force and gravity can unite?

I apologize for grammatical and grammatical errors, if it exist.
This is the link to the research paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3573

Comment: ....as long as you are aware that maverick paper was written in Feb 2012, and the Higgs was discovered in July of that year, and its mass  is now pretty firmly established. The paper you are reading is speculating about the nonexistence of birds...