# Can the low Higgs mass solve the problem of fine tuning of the Fermi constant?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, standard-model, higgs, fine-tuning

The Standard Model indicates that quantum corrections to the Fermi constant make its value surprisingly large, and that its value could be closer to the Newtonian constant of gravitation unless there is a precise cancellation between the abstract value of it and its quantum corrections. Could the low mass of the Higgs boson play a role in solving the problem of fine tuning for the value of the Fermi constant?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747988/2451